# Git Push error (large files)

Tags: git

I have some video files in a local git repo that were preventing me from doing a push.

I have removed these files from my local repository using:

```
git rm static/video -r -f
```

but when I try to git push they are still preventing my branch to be pushed (since they are over the file size limit).

How can I fix this?

```
git push        

Counting objects: 2754, done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (1558/1558), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (2064/2064), 317.03 MiB | 1.60 MiB/s, done.
    Total 2064 (delta 1640), reused 622 (delta 496)
    remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1640/1640), completed with 618 local objects.
    remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
    remote: error: Trace: 23f34cbc9f2adebd84c33f871ab54e68
    remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
```

Comment: The large files are still part of the history and you must remove it there.  Look into using repo cleaner.

Comment: In the future, consider using `git-lfs`.....

Comment: how do i remove them from the history?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/7976758